# Which transistor is the best for switching on/off a LED with an ESP32?

Tags: transistors, led, esp32

I have bought a transistor set a while ago and I never used it so I thought I would give it a shot to make a simple circuit. I'm very new to electronics and the math behind it so I'm sorry if it's a really simple question. These are the transistors:

[image]

I have built a simple schematic to the best of my understanding:

[image]

Now I'm scratching my head on how to calculate the resistor value and which of the transistors will suit my application best. The LED is a 3 V SMD2835 that consumes 120 mA.

Comment: The LED and the transistor will quickly burn out unless you add a series current-limiting resistor. With a 120mA collector load then the base current should be 12mA. Use a 2N2222 or a 2N3904 and use the base-emitter forward voltage (0.7V) of the transistor to calculate the base resistor. Use Ohm's Law  and the power supply voltage to calculate the new resistor.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you would search data sheets for each transistor and look up what their properties are, such as if they can switch 120mA or not.

Also the LED would burn up without a resistor in series. The LED needing 3V to work may be difficult to power from 3.3V which is only 0.3V more, so limiting the current to 120mA will not be very precise, as LEDs usually have some tolerance.

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: I recommend to read the data sheets how much each transistor is rated for, add a resistor and consider using 5V supply for a 3V LED.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a 3.3V supply, but I tested and it gets perfectly bright with 3.3V